# How to find Variance Inflation factor in python and What should be the parameters in VIF function?

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, logistic-regression, variance

```
    statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence.variance_inflation_factor(exog, exog_idx)

Parameters: 
 exog (ndarray) – design matrix with all explanatory variables, as      for example used in regression
 exog_idx (int) – index of the exogenous variable in the columns of exog
```

I am finding difficulty in understanding the parameters. 
For example I have a dataset with 20 variables, and one class variable (total 21 variables)

Var1 var2 Var3 Var4 class variable

so, exog will be all of these variables including class variable ?
or exog will be all of these variables excluding class variable ?

What should be exog_idx ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variance Inflation Factor in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658379/variance-inflation-factor-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

I also find statsmodels documents are extremely unhelpful since they don't give any examples sometimes it is hard to understand.

I was also looking for some answers and examples there are some solution suggestions, but let me try to explain.

exog -> independent variables or features you are using to predict your target

exog_idx -> index of the variable

The way you do this is a list comprehension, assume you have pandas data frame (df):

```
vif = pd.DataFrame([variance_inflation_factor(df.values, i) for i in range(df.shape[1]), index=df.columns, columns=['VIF_value'])
```

This will create a dataset called vif and you will see VIF values for each feature you have.

Comment: can this `df` contain the actual dependent variable?